# loading values into select list or type in a text box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a requirement that

- if a `$data` array has elements, then my form will contain a 
  list with all of those values
- if the `$data` array is empty, then one text field will be there.

Either editing in a text box or selecting from the list should work. The returned form values should match what's selected or typed in that field.

How can I implement this with PHP, JavaScript or Ajax?

Comment: i suggest you at leat make some kind of effort

Comment: after the word requirement, everyone will stop to read your problem... post some attempt first (code)

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, you need to make some effort but the following will help you achieve what you want:

```
<?php if (count($data) > 0) {  ?> // Count $data, if its more than 0 then make select object
<select name="mySelect">
    <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<?php } else { ?> // If count is 0 then make an input text
<input type="text" name="myText" />
<?php } ?>
```